# Getting error while trying to get image path from website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and trying to scrape product from amazone. I able to get almost all data of single product but image path giving me error.

**Error :**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Code I am trying :

in `items.py` I have class and added this as well with other fields :

```
productImage = Field()
```

in other file `test.py` I have wrote like this to get image path :

```
 productimage = hxs.select('(//li[contains(@class,"imageThumbnail")]//following-sibling::span[@class="a-button-text"]//img//@src)[1]').extract()
   converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
   converter.ignore_links = True
   print("productImage :" + converter.handle(productimages))
```

I also tried :

```
   productimage = hxs.select('(//li[contains(@class,"imageThumbnail")]//following-sibling::span[@class="a-button-text"]//img//@src)[1]').extract()[0]
```

Xpath is correct and I already evaluated it.

Comment: as the error says, `productimage` is a list, maybe try with `productimage[0]`

Comment: @eLRuLL - No luck

Comment: What's the error with `productimage[0]`?

Comment: @Granitosaurus- There is no error in that case but it also did not print any data for image path

Comment: You have no `replace()` calls in your code related to image path. Obviously you have an error in another part of your `test.py`

Comment: Please show how you've validated the xpath.